# Generate Excel from Kendo Grid after Clicking Custom Button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to generate Excel after clicking a custom button(not export button) from Kendo grid and Save the file.

Pls Help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want the user to choose where to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom button in the grid

```
.ToolBar(tools =>
                {                       
                    tools.Custom().Text("Export to Excel").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "exporTtoExcelClass" });
            })
```

And on the grid bound function you need to add function

```
function Grid_DataBound() {
      var grid = $('#YourGrid').data('kendoGrid');
      var exportButton = grid.element.find(".exporTtoExcelClass");
      exportButton.unbind("click");
      exportButton.on("click", function (args) {
            kendo.ui.progress($("#YourGrid"), true);
            var grid1 = $("#YourGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid1.saveAsExcel();
            kendo.ui.progress($("#YourGrid"), false);
           return false;
     });
}
```

Comment: Be careful when binding events on `dataBound` event, as it can be called more than once, duplicating the bindings in the element.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, Thank you for your valuable feedback/suggestion. I have edited solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Diptee , its worked perfectly but instead of downloading the excel file i want to save it in a custom folder in application level.